# Авторизация на сайте через вк

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, авторизация, oauth

делаю авторизацию на сайте через вк, но столкнулся с проблемой, я формирую ссылку

```
<?php
    $params = [
        'client_id' => '51500888',
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://topdrop.fun/core/OAuth/vk/oauth.php',
        'scope' => 'email',
        'response_type' => 'code',
    ];
    
    $url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));
?>
```

перенаправляю пользователя на oauth.php, проблема в том что когда нажимаешь на ссылку вылазит ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

oauth.php:

```
 <?php
    if (!empty($_GET['code'])) {
      $params = [
        'client_id' => '51500888',
        'client_secret' => '||||||||||||||',
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://topdrop.fun/core/auth/vk/oauth.php',
        'code' => $_GET['code'],
      ];
    
      $data = file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params)));
      $data = json_decode($data, true);
      if (!empty($data['access_token'])) {
        print_r($data['access_token']);
        include __DIR__ . '/../../database/db.php';
    
        $params = [
          'v' => '5.81',
          'uids' => $data['user_id'],
          'access_token' => $data['access_token'],
        ];
    
        $info = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params)));
        $info = json_decode($info, true);
    
        $user_name = $info['first_name'] . $info['id'];
    
        $db->query("INSERT INTO `users`(`user_name`, `access_token`) VALUES ('$info[first_name]', '$data[access_token])");
    
        setcookie("access_token", $data['access_token'], time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), '/');
      }
    }
```

Настройки в приложении:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл виновника проблемы, в redirect_uri был указан старый адрес